# Vue apollo - send authorization over websockets

Tags: vuejs2, graphql, hasura, vue-apollo

I have a vue web app from which I'm trying to run a subscription using a hasura query.

My problem is that I cannot pass to the Websocket request an authorization token as the backend expects.

These are my current settings:

```
const token = localStorage.getItem("token") || null;

const options = {
  httpUri: //graphql http endpoint,
  wsUri: //graphql ws endpoint
};
let link = new HttpLink({
  uri: options.httpUri
});

// Create the subscription websocket link if available
if (options.wsUri) {
  const wsLink = new WebSocketLink(
    new SubscriptionClient(options.wsUri, {
      lazy: true,
      reconnect: true,
      connectionParams: {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      }
    })
  );

  // using the ability to split links, you can send data to each link
  // depending on what kind of operation is being sent
  link = split(
    // split based on operation type
    ({ query }) => {
      const definition = getMainDefinition(query);
      return (
        definition.kind === "OperationDefinition" &&
        definition.operation === "subscription"
      );
    },
    wsLink,
    link
  );
}

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  // return the headers to the context so httpLink can read them
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : ""
    }
  };
});
const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
  if (graphQLErrors)
    graphQLErrors.map(({ message }) => {
      if (message.includes("unauthorized")) {
        EventBus.$emit("unauthorized");
      }
    });

  if (networkError) console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`);
});

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: ApolloLink.from([errorLink, authLink, link]),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  connectToDevTools: true
});

const apolloProvider = new VueApollo({
  defaultClient: apolloClient
});
```

When I try to run the subscription I get

> HTTP Authentication failed; no valid credentials available

And in the ws request header I cannot see my Authorization bearer set.

A side info I need authorization for both http and ws requests

Answer (score 1):

I think `errorLink` or `authLink` unexpectedly change websocket header token. You try modifying a bit:

```js
    const httpLink = from([
      authLink,
      // errorLink,
      new HttpLink({
        uri: Config.httpDataHost,
        headers: {
          [XHasuraClientName]: Config.hasuraClientName
        }
      })
    ]);
    
    const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({ ... });
    const link = ...
    const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
      link: ApolloLink.from([errorLink, link]),
      cache: new InMemoryCache(),
      connectToDevTools: true
    });
```

If it doesn't work, you can try commenting `errorLink` to check. Another thing is, you shouldn't get token globally, but use lazy function so ApolloClient can always get latest access token from local storage

```js
const getIdToken = () => localStorage.getItem('token') || null;

const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
  uri: options.wsUri,
  options: {
    connectionParams: () => ({
      headers: {
        Authorization: getIdToken(),
      }
    }),
    ...
  }
});
```

PS: I have an example repository with React + Apollo Client 3.0. Although you are using Vue.js,Apollo Client construction is the same https://github.com/hgiasac/ra-hasura-typescript-boilerplate/blob/auth-jwt/src/shared/ApolloClient.ts

Comment: I tried commenting the `erroLink` ,  but still no headers sent to the ws request, the `connectionParams` function is never called

Comment: do you run subscription after authentication? Subscription won't run until first subscription call with `lazy` option

Comment: Yes, I found the problem - I am using the hasura engine inside docker, and nginx as reverse proxy to that hasura instance, so I had to create a route in nginx config file to point to the inner docker hasura engine, but your github example really helped, thanks a lot for this